# rake db:seed give validation error: Email already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rspec, rake

I am setting up a fork on one of the projects.

After creating the database I:

```
rake db:schema:load
```

then

```
rake db:seed
```

to load seed data.

This throws an error

> rake aborted! Validation failed: Webiso account has already been
>   taken, Email has already been taken

Where Webiso and Email are the fields in one of the tables.

I have dropped, created and loaded the schema again.

I have tried the buzzwords. db:reset, db:setup etc.

Nothing works.

Any help would be appreciated.

db/seeds.rb

```
# This file should contain all the record creation needed to seed the database with its default values.
# The data can then be loaded with the rake db:seed (or created alongside the db with db:setup).
#
# Examples:
#
#   cities = City.create([{ :name => 'Chicago' }, { :name => 'Copenhagen' }])
#   Mayor.create(:name => 'Daley', :city => cities.first)


require 'factory_girl'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :xx, :parent => :person do
    first_name "xx"
    last_name "xx"
    twiki_name "xx"
    human_name "xx"
    email "xxx@xx"
    is_staff 1

  end


  factory :ed, :parent => :person do
    first_name "Ed"
    last_name "xx"
    twiki_name "xx"
    human_name "xx"
    email "xx@xx"
    is_staff 1
    image_uri "/images/staff/xx.jpg"
  end


  factory :anubhav, :parent => :person do
    is_student 1
    is_part_time 0
    graduation_year "2021"
    masters_program "SE"
    masters_track "Tech"
    twiki_name "AnubhavAeron"
    first_name "Anubhav"
    last_name "Aeron"
    human_name "Anubhav Aeron"
    email "xx@xx"
    webiso_account "x@xx"
  end

end

Factory(:task_type, :name => "Working on deliverables")
Factory(:task_type, :name => "Readings")
Factory(:task_type, :name => "Meetings")
Factory(:task_type, :name => "Other")


xx = Factory.create(:xx)
xx = Factory.create(:xx)
Factory.create(:anubhav)
Factory.create(:team_terrific) #This will create awe_smith, betty_ross, and charlie_moss

FactoryGirl.create(:presentation_feedback_questions, :label => "Content", :text => "Did the talk cover all the content suggested on the checklist? (ie goals, progress, and the process for achieving the goals, outcomes)")
FactoryGirl.create(:presentation_feedback_questions, :label => "Organization", :text => "How logical was the organization? How smooth were transactions between points and parts of the talk?  Was the talk focused? To the point?  Were the main points clearly stated? easy to find?")
FactoryGirl.create(:presentation_feedback_questions, :label => "Visuals", :text => "Were they well-designed? Were all of them readable? Were they helpful? Were they manipulated well?")
FactoryGirl.create(:presentation_feedback_questions, :label => "Delivery", :text => "Bodily delivery: (eye-contact, gestures, energy)    Vocal delivery: (loudness, rate, articulation) Question handling (poise, tact, team support; did the team answer the question asked?)")
```

Comment: Please post your `db/seeds.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

This (typo?) may be the cause of your error:

```
xx = Factory.create(:xx)
xx = Factory.create(:xx)
```

which will try to create two `Person` instances and save them to the database. Both of them share the same attributes (email) which triggers your `validates_uniqueness_of :email` (or similar) validation in your `Person` model.

---

N.B. if it's not a typo, please have a look into [sequences](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#sequences) and/or [Faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker).

Comment: not a typo. I xx just a cover up of the original data

Comment: When I command:                                                             rake db:schema:load. Things go fine. It loads the schema. On rake db:seed. It throws validation error ! That email already exists. How is it loading the same data twice.

Comment: Your factory does not provide the data needed to (idempotently) build and save a valid `Person` record (i.e. generating **the same** email address over and over). Just apply a *Factory Girl sequence* to the email attribute.

Comment: I have put different email ids for each user So I would not require sequence. For the purpose of keeping it hidden publicly I have used xx

Comment: Then provide a better masked and concise `seeds.rb`.